# java.io.NotSerializableException: oshi.hardware.platform.Windows.WindowsCentralProcessor

Tags: java, socket, serialización

**Hola, buenas, tengo una duda, mi programa simula conexión cliente-servidor y utilizando la librería oshi intentamos obtener las especificaciones de la computadora tanto de uno como del otro pero a la hora de correrlo nos arroja este error:**

Cliente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servidor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nuestro código:

Cliente:

```
package Main;


import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.CentralProcessor;
import oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        HardwareAbstractionLayer hardware = systemInfo.getHardware();
        CentralProcessor procesador = hardware.getProcessor();
        System.out.println(procesador);
        Socket s = null;
        try {
            // instancio el server con la IP y el PORT
            s = new Socket("25.3.205.91", 5432);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

            // envio un nombre
            oos.writeObject(procesador);

            // recibo la respuesta (el saludo personalizado)
            String ret = (String)ois.readObject();

            // muestro la respuesta que envio el server
            System.out.println("El resultado:" + ret);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ois != null) {
                ois.close();
            }
            if (oos != null) {
                oos.close();
            }
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí en cliente intentamos enviar los parametros con la librería oshi para el servidor.

Servidor:

```
package Main;

import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import oshi.SystemInfo;
import oshi.hardware.CentralProcessor;
import oshi.hardware.HardwareAbstractionLayer;
import java.io.Serializable;


public class Server implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SystemInfo systemInfo = new SystemInfo();
        ObjectInputStream ois = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        //HardwareAbstractionLayer hardware = systemInfo.getHardware();
        //CentralProcessor procesador = hardware.getProcessor();

        Socket s = null;
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5432);

        while (true) {
            try {
                // el ServerSocket me da el Socket
                s = ss.accept();
                // informacion en la consola
                System.out.println("Se conectaron desde la IP: "
                        + s.getInetAddress());

                // enmascaro la entrada y salida de bytes
                ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                // leo el nombre que envia el cliente
                String pro = (String) ois.readObject();

                oos.writeObject(pro);
                System.out.println("Resultado enviado...");
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (oos != null) {
                    oos.close();
                }
                if (ois != null) {
                    ois.close();
                }
                if (s != null) {
                    s.close();
                }
                System.out.println("Conexion cerrada!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En servidor intentamos establecer la conexión, leer la información del cliente, enviar resultados e informar las entradas de IP.

¿Alguna solución? Gracias! :)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tienes que aprender es que para que un Objeto viaje en la red debe implementar la interfaz `java.io.Serializable` y revisando el código fuente de `oshio` la clase `WindowsCentralProcessor` que te indica el error no implementa `java.io.Serializable` por eso te retorna la excepción `NotSerializableException` , la solución simple seria crear tu propia clase o jerarquía de clases que implementen `java.io.Serializable` y cargar ahi los datos que necesitas enviar o bajar el codigo de la librería `oshio` y modificar los objetos.